# Bokeh Hovertool for second plot in a figure

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

So I have a bar chart with a line on top of it. It works fine except that I cannot get the hovertool to work on the added line graph. I am not sure how to complete the code below to get the hovering to work for the line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, HoverTool

def convert_to_categorical(months):
    month_names = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    return [month_names[m-1] for m in months]


def NetRevGraph(NetRev, Vol):

    # bar chart (hovering works fine)
    x1 = [int(i['Month']) for i in NetRev]
    y1 = [i['Amount'] for i in NetRev]
    m1 = convert_to_categorical(x1)
    tooltip_net_rev = [("Net Revenue", "$y"),]
    source_net_rev = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=m1, y=y1, ))
    p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400, x_range=m1, tooltips=tooltip_net_rev)
    p.vbar(x='x', width=0.5, bottom=0, top='y', color="#B3DE69", source=source_net_rev)

    # add line graph (can seem to complete this so that hover works)
    x2 = [int(i['MonthNum']) for i in Vol]
    y2 = [i['Val'] for i in Vol]
    m2 = convert_to_categorical(x2)
    source_vol = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=m2, y=y2, ))
    tooltip_net_vol = [("Volume", "$y"), ]
    p.extra_y_ranges = {"Vol": Range1d(start=min(y2), end=max(y2))}
    p.add_tools()
    p.line(x='x', y='y', line_width=2, y_range_name="Vol", color="black", source=source_vol)
    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Vol"), 'right')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to use the add_tools method for both the bar and the line to add HoverTool for both.

updated figure to take no hover arguments. Gave the bar chart a variable name and then used it to add the hover tool.

```
p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400, x_range=m1)
bar = p.vbar(x='x', width=0.5, bottom=0, top='y', color="#B3DE69", source=source_net_rev)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[bar], tooltips=tooltip_net_rev))
```

Did the same with the line graph

```
line = p.line(x='x', y='y', line_width=2, y_range_name="Vol", color="black", source=source_vol)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[line], tooltips=tooltip_net_vol))
```